# How to use existing cookie with selenium and Python in order to login

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am developing a Python script with Selenium to make some automation on a website.

The script need to login first to have access to specific pages for my automation.

I would like to skip this login process by using cookie session like PhantomBuster does.

It exists here only solution to save a cookie after a first login and re-use this cookie to skip login process. This is not what I want.

I want my script load existing cookie from normal chrome or firefox browser in order to connect to website automatically without typing email/password.

Is it possible with Python or Javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cookie = {'key': 'value'}
browser.add_cookie(cookie)
```

You may have to hit the root of the site first then add the cookie and then attempt to get to pages past the authentication.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I may ha e explained badly my issue.

Comment: I need to use existing cookie. In chrome, cookies are stored in sqlite with crypted vamues.i can’t use your solution.